# Quiet Desert areas around Los Angeles to Record in

Tags: field-recording, desert, quiet

Hi Everybody,

I was wondering if anyone had any favorite quiet, secluded locations outside of Los Angeles where they like to record. The ideal place would be reasonably quiet and away from spying eyes. Thanks.

Tony

Answer (score 3):

I would investigate around the outskirts of [Palmdale](http://maps.google.com/maps?client=safari&rls=en&oe=UTF-8&q=palmdale+ca&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hq=&hnear=0x80c25784ec70ddb5:0x6a6c792dad12e03a,Palmdale,+CA&gl=us&sa=X&ei=VUbTULTKLObfiAKXpoCgDg&ved=0CJsBELYD).

Comment: there are 3 airfields situated near palmdale, are they closed?

Comment: These are military bases, LAX and Burbank flight paths are the airports to worry about in LA.

Answer (score 1):

Speaking from a bit of experience, you are going to experience urban noise pollution even at great distances outside of Los Angeles County. Between the freeways and flight paths you'll be fighting the noise at every turn. If you really want to find a (relatively) quiet space I'd head for Death Valley.

Comment: Speaking from my experience as well, even going out to my favorite desert areas which are 250 miles away from LA, I still get noise pollution encroaching on me every so often (even LAX flight patterns or joyriding Cessnas from nearby rural airports!). As Jay has said, Death Valley is probably the best spot you'll find, or else somewhere in Nevada. It also depends upon what's being recorded. Ambience is more demanding than say, gunshots or vehicles.

Answer (score 0):

Here's where Charles Maynes records, he says it's near Burbank:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uL350lOQ8I0

BTW, I can swear that there is a point in desert where many Hollywood gunshots get recorded. I've seen this picture of a desert with a faraway mountain (where they get the slapback i suppose) several times, but maybe all deserts look alike?